# Blinking html by changing the background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

originally I'm using jquery fade in and fade out to do blinking for a fixed number of times like below:

```
function blink(selector, counter) {
    $(selector).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(500, function() {
            if (counter++ < 10) {
                blink(this, counter);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now I want to change it to using jquery to change the background color to do blinking effect. But my coding don't seems to work:

```
function blink(selector, counter) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(selector).css("background-color", "red");
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(selector).css("background-color", "black");
    }, 500);
    if (counter++ < 10) {
        blink(this, counter);
    }
}
```

It just blink for once. Anything wrong guys?

I try the below but doesn't work too:

```
function blink(selector, counter) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(selector).css("background-color", "red", function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).css("background-color", "black", function() {
                    if (counter++ < 10) {
                        blink(this, counter);
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: do you want interval 500 ms between red and black?

Comment: Not really. Any value also can. I try 1000 but still blink once

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling blink recursively but there is no callback for when the timeout finishes so it is adding all of the timeout events at the same time instead of one after the other (well not exactly the same time but you get the idea).

You can try it this way:

```
function blink(selector, counter) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if( $(selector).hasClass('black') ) {
            $(selector).removeClass('black').addClass('red');
        } else {
            $(selector).removeClass('red').addClass('black');
        }

        if( counter++ < 10 ) { // to get the result you want this number may need to be 20 for 10 blinks
            blink(selector, counter);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

I would set the classes black and red to utilize the background color.

**UPDATE**

Your second example fails because jQuery doesn't accept a callback function as an argument for the css method. So doing the following won't log anything to the console:

```
$('.my-element').css('background', 'red', function() {
     console.log('this will not log anything because jquery does not call this callback function');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For background color animation you would probably need jquery-ui library or you could use css animation to do this:

```js
function blink(selector) {
  $(selector).addClass('aniBg');
}

blink("div");
```

```css
.aniBg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px black;
  animation: animeBG 2s 5;
  -webkit-animation: colorchange 2s 5;
}
@keyframes animeBG {
  0% { background: red; }
  100% { background: black; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>color animation</div>
```

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/am6sxqhm/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function blink(selector, counter) {
    var t = counter * 1000;

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(selector).css("background-color", "red");
    }, t);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(selector).css("background-color", "black");
    }, t + 500);

    if (counter++ < 10) {
      blink(selector, counter);
    }
  }

  blink($('div'), 1);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

this may work for your need